# Playing with unordered_multimap

Tags: c++, c++11, hashmap, unordered-map

So, guys, I am playing with `std::unordered multimap` just for fun. I'd like to store (in this example) `unsigned short`s, with a custom hash and equal.

What's the funny part? Having two items being equal if they're both even or odd.

So, as far as I understand, I can't use `std::unordered_map`, even though actual values differ: the custom predicate says otherwise. (correct me if I'm wrong, obviously!)

So to recap: I store *different* integers and therefore *different hashes*, but their values under the predicate *might be the same*.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

class tt
{
public:

    tt(const unsigned short v = 0) : i(v) { };

    unsigned short i;
};

class tt_hash
{
public:
    size_t operator()(const tt &v) const
    {
        auto f = std::hash<unsigned short>();
        return f(v.i);
    };
};

class tt_equal
{
public:
    bool operator()(const tt &u, const tt &v) const
    {
        return (u.i % 2) == (v.i % 2);
    };
};

typedef std::unordered_multimap<tt, bool, tt_hash, tt_equal> mymap;

// Print all values that match a criteria
void f(const mymap &m, unsigned short c)
{
    auto range = m.equal_range(c);

    auto target = range.first;

    if (target == m.end())
    {
        std::cout << "not found : " << (int) c << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        for (auto i = target; i != range.second; i++)
            std::cout << "there is  : " << (int) i->first.i << " : " << i->second << std::endl;
    }

}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{    
    mymap m;

    m.emplace(std::make_pair(tt(3), false));
    m.emplace(std::make_pair(tt(10), true));
    m.emplace(std::make_pair(tt(4), true));
    m.emplace(std::make_pair(tt(23), false));

    std::cout << "size " << m.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "buck " << m.bucket_count() << std::endl;

    int c = 0;

    for (auto i = m.begin(); i != m.end(); i++)
        std::cout << "# " << c++ << " : " << (int) i->first.i << " : " << i->second << std::endl;

    f(m, 3);

    return 0;
}
```

So, when I execute the code above I find the correct values, 3, 10, 4, 23 (not in this order of course).

Unexpectedly, when printing all the values *matching 3* calling `f()`, I get two answers, 3 and 23; but when I ask for 1000, I expected to have all the even numbers printed, but I was wrong:

```
size 4
buck 5
# 0 : 4 : 1
# 1 : 10 : 1
# 2 : 3 : 0
# 3 : 23 : 0
there is  : 10 : 1
```

Am I missing something here? (the answer is obviously yes)

Comment: the equal in the unordered containers is for identifying stored elements, so you essentially reduce the possible values to store to two (odd or even) and have to adjust your hashfunction accordingly (I  would recommend x & 1)

Answer (score 6):

What you are doing is undefined behavior: equal elements should have equal hash values. According to the standard (emphasis mine)

**23.2.5 Unordered associative containers [unord.req]**

> 5 Two values k1 and k2 of type Key are considered equivalent if the
>   container’s key equality predicate returns true when passed those
>   values. **If k1 and k2 are equivalent, the container’s hash function
>   shall return the same value for both**.

Since you define equivalence in terms of modulo 2, you also need to use the hash function on the modulo 2 of the integer being passed. It also means that you need `std::unordered_multimap` as soon as you have more than 2 elements.

Comment: Mmh... I'd really like to store them efficiently, but not on only two buckets, that would defeat the whole purpose of using an unordered_multimap. Any suggestion?

Comment: why not use `typedef std::unordered_multiset<tt>[2] mymap;` I.e. you hash `tt` objects into 2 different sets, depending on whether the modulo 2 value is 0 or 1. Of course, now you need to define `tt_equal` as `u.i == v.i` (i.e. without the `% 2`).

Comment: Because the objective is to make predicates at runtime (given a compile-time template of course). So, I'd like  to find all values that share particular bits, for example, or that are multiples of five. With a hash table, I have almost constant seek time, and of course at most N, while not maintaining any order (I don't care about order of values).

Comment: @senseiwa but the unordered containers have *compile-time* predicates, so if you want multiple unrelated *run-time* predicate searches, you are problably best of with a plain `std::vector` and `std:find_if` (which has `O(N)` complexity for `N` elements). That's simply the price of flexibility: a container is optimized only for searches that you specify at compile-time. If you want a fixed number of compile-time searches, try [Boost.MultiIndex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) which allows multiple hashed indices (give a predicate for each index).

Comment: Yes, I do understand that I need compile-time predicates. But what if I want a predicate that tests if two numbers are equal modulo `N`, with `N` being a run-time variable? 

I understand I'm doing something out of the line here, but it's something that I find it interesting.

Comment: @senseiwa like I said, for that kind of flexibility try a `std::vector` with `std::find_if` and a lambda predicate. Or maybe invent some kind of clever new data structure, but AFAIK, none of the Standard Containers will give you that.